# Slicing R Data Frame Based on Column Index

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
data <- data.frame(1:4,5:8,9:12,13:16)
```

And I have a list of column indexes

```
col_index <- c(1,4,3,2)
```

For each row, I would like to select the cell specified in the column index, and return the following list of values: 1, 8, 11, 14.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: @RonakShah, I think you have the row/column reversed

Comment: @r2evans ohhh...I see now. Thanks. I think then the duplicate isn't correct?

Comment: The dupe is applicable, but is opposite this: the dupe wants *each row given columns*, and this one is *each column given rows*. The premise of `cbind(...)` applies, and I think if you repost that as a comment it'd still be useful (despite the dupe).

Comment: `data[cbind(col_index, seq_len(ncol(data)))]`

Comment: @r2evans thanks, I agree it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @RUMe, that's not what I said. It's applicable as a duplicate question, despite the fact that in *that* question they want all rows and specific columns, whereas you want all columns and specific rows. The logic and method are identical, you just need to reverse the indices. The combination of `cbind` and `seq`uencing along one of the frame axes is perfectly appropriate, and resolves your question. Please don't think that closing as a "dupe" is a bad thing or reflects negatively. The only thing I infer from "dupe" is that you didn't find it when you searched for prior art.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice.index:

```
> slice.index(data,1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```

Then construct a matrix

```
> matrix(rep(col_index,4),4,4,byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    3    2
[2,]    1    4    3    2
[3,]    1    4    3    2
[4,]    1    4    3    2
```

Create a mask

```
> slice.index(data,1) == matrix(rep(col_index,4),4,4,byrow=TRUE)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Eventually

```
> data[slice.index(data,1) == matrix(rep(col_index,4),4,4,byrow=TRUE)]
[1]  1  8 11 14
```

Comment: In all my years of R, I've *never* used or even heard of `slice.index`. Interesting function.